# Remove file path from lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, include

I would like to achieve the following ornament:
For the university we have to convert code into a PDF. To make this easier I use the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\includecode}[2][code]{\lstinputlisting[escapechar=, style=code, title=#2]{#2} \bigskip}
```

However, the title displays the entire path of the file, not just the file name itself.
How can I fix this?

Edit:
This is the command I use for including files:

```
\includecode{Intelli/src/a19/a/Immobilie.java}
```

Regards

Andi

UPDATE: 
My final code. Maybe someone might like this solution in the future.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\captcode}[1]{\filename@parse{#1}\filename@base.\filename@ext}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\includecode}[2][code]{\lstinputlisting[escapechar=, style=code, title=\captcode{#2}]{#2} \bigskip}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel has a file name parser that can be used to split the path into components:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \filename@parse{#1}%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Path: & #1\\
    Area: & \filename@area\\
    Base: & \filename@base\\
    Extension:  & \filename@ext\\
    Name: & \filename@base.\filename@ext\\
  \end{tabular}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \test{Intelli/src/a19/a/Immobilie.java}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]